# Is Yonder: The Cloud Catcher Chronicles safe for children?

Tags: yonder-the-cloud-catcher-chronicles

My niece is 10 years old and I just gave her a steam account. I'm deciding on what games to buy for her and I saw [Yonder: The Cloud Catcher Chronicles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=docsD5hcMJI). But at the trailer, it says "Rated E: Crude Humor." What kind of "Crude humor" does it contain? Does it have curse words and ***mature*** jokes and such? I want a real, peaceful game. No ***horrible*** jokes. ***NO BAD WORDS.*** And absolutely ***NOTHING SEXUAL.***

P.S. yeah I guess I could spend 4 hours watching a gameplay of it in youtube but i don't really have the luxury of time.

Comment: to be honest i'm the kind of person who thinks people should review games themselves rather that rely on the ratings. a great example Atelier Totori which was released as PG in Australia but it's remake got upgraded to R18+ for sexual violence which i will say is wrong as the remake has no extra content and i've played both and the only violence i saw was the normal monster killing so one of the ratings is lying for a game which saw little improvement (should note that the original game's PG rating stated nothing about sexual violence)

Comment: @Memor-X most of your comment has nothing to do with what the question is asking. They're obviously not just judging it based on the rating, or they wouldn't have asked us.

Comment: @Memor-X it's because i'm not buying the game so that ***I*** could play it. I don't want to spend double just to review it. Again, it's for my ***niece.*** I also mentioned I don't have the luxury of spending 4 hours watching gameplay. So I came here to ask those who know who could just take 2 seconds to reply "It's good" or "Not good." Thank you for your time.

Comment: really though. so if I was choosing between 10 games, I'm supposed to make a decision by ***buying the ten games, playing them, then choosing which was best?*** OKAY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked the ESRB rating for this game. According to the rating at http://esrb.org/ratings/Synopsis.aspx?Certificate=34954&Title=Yonder%3A%20The%20Cloud%20Catcher%20Chronicles, the crude humor is just some fart and poo jokes.

> This is a role-playing game in which players explore an island (Gemea) in an attempt to dispel an evil force. Players interact with people, craft items, raise livestock, and farm the land. One area contains a bog called the “Farty Fen” where flatulence sounds can be heard; another area allows players to tend cattle-like creatures that leave “poo coils” around their pens.